My end users use either a pc or a mac. How can my VBA code tell the difference when it runs?
My end users may use either Mac or pc. My Excel VBA code needs to refer to a separate file, using its path and filename. I need to detect which system the code is running on so I can adjust a back slash in the filename to a forward slash. Can VBA detect which system it is running on?

You can use conditional compilation for this.

...eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-directive

Use the Mac conditional compilation constant. For example:
Sub Foo()
#If Mac Then
    Debug.Print "I'm on a Mac"
#Else
    Debug.Print "I'm not on a Mac"
#End If
End Sub

For details, see this page on Compiler constants

Many thanks, Stack Overflow, for your help.
